# jar version issue or scala issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I found a JsonToCSV.scala program in GitHub repository https://github.com/salamonpavel/jsonToCsv and I am trying to run **JsonToCSV.scala** program in Scala IDE, I want to run it locally, So i am downloading Jar as mentioned in sbt file in github link.

I am not able to resolve the error i am getting and which jar version should i download please guide me here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2HRv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue .... by adding all jars from sparks latest jar folder with